# Ajax requests do not stop when Ruby session expires

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, session

I have read a lot about how to keep session from expiring when ajax is running. However, I want something that does exactly the reverse. I want the webpage to stop making AJAX requests as soon as the session expires. I am using Ruby on Rails to design the page and JQuery to call those methods. Currently, as soon as the session expires, all AJAX requests are redirected to login page as per my code on application controller. This causes thousands of hits on the login page. I want these requests to stop as soon as the session expires. How do I do this?

I am using `setInterval` method on the view page to call those methods.

Comment: Sounds like you're using polling. How about a more push based method, like websockets/Pusher.com, etc.

Comment: I don't really know. I am actually not allowed to change the structure of the code by using new API. All I can do is find the defect and fix it :(

Comment: I tried checking the session value in the view every time the AJAX method is called. But checking session value called the aplication controller, thereby refersing the session value which was wxactly what I did not want in the first place.
Any help?

Comment: In your endpoint where you determine the session is no longer valid than just don't do a redirect but return back an acceptable HTTP status code - then in your AJAX callback handler detect this code and remove the setInterval to prevent future AJAX calls from being made.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that and report back.

Comment: The guys I am working for ended up commenting the AJAX calls. Never got to test it. :(
But thanks, Cody, for your help.